# Why does the word "experience" have a different initial vowel from that in "expert" and "expertise"?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, linguistics

In American English, the pronunciation of the words "experience", "expert", and "expertise" can be transcribed as /ɪkˈspɪr.i.əns/, /ˈɛk.spɚt/, /ˌɛk.spɚˈtiːz/ respectively. Can one identify a synchronic linguistic reason or a historical one for the different initial vowel in these words (/ɪ/ versus /ɛ/)? In both "experience" and "expertise", the initial vowel doesn't carry the primary stress, so it's not clear to me whether stress is relevant here.

Comment: That pronunciation of "experience" is one dialectical form.  Some people pronounce it that way, while others are closer to "expert".  And many people use both pronunciations, depending on context.

Comment: @HotLicks I'd be interested in a reference to a dictionary or another source that gives a transcription with initial /ɛ/ for the word "experience". Additionally, does it work the other way around (that is, are there people who say /ˈɪk.spɚt/ for "expert")? If there are people who strictly maintain a difference with respect to the initial vowel, how can that be linguistically explained?

Comment: [Kenyon and Knott](https://archive.org/details/pronouncingdicti00unse/mode/2up?view=theater) gives both pronunciations for _expert_, but it's limited to American English. it's also almost a hundred years old. But initial stressed vowels like _expert_ are always different from initial unstressed vowels like _experience_. English unstressed vowels centralize, shorten, and neutralize whenever they can.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks you. How can we think of unstressed /ɪ/ corresponding to stressed /ɛ/ in light of the statement "English unstressed vowels centralize, shorten, and neutralize whenever they can"? 
Can we meaningfully think of /ɪ/ as being more central than /ɛ/? To my ears, /ɪ/ sounds closer to a cardinal front /i/ as opposed to a central /ə/. So I'm curious to know if unstressed /ɪ/ corresponding to stressed /ɛ/ is more of an English-specific behavior or if there's rather a cross-linguistic tendency for /ɪ/ to be the unstressed variant of another vowel phoneme.

Comment: @ŠāhbandarBandūra /ɪ/ is an abstract phoneme. What is actually said in a given instance by a given speaker is a **phone**, and not an abstract phoneme. Your question is meaningless because you're taking the abstract pronunciation as a fact, instead of a written approximation. It's the difference between official reality and spoken language.

Comment: @JohnLawler I already understand that. Are you saying that the spectrum of phonetic realizations of /ɪ/ *in English* is more central than the spectrum of /ɛ/? How does one measure the central-ness of a phone? Did you mean that in a different language a phoneme represented as /ɪ/ could have phonetic realizations that are less central than /ɪ/ in English? I don't have formal training in linguistics, so answering such questions would help me.

Comment: @ŠāhbandarBandūra I'm saying that, first of all, the range of all English vowel phonemes that one chooses to write as the underlying phoneme in a given word is already very very large. Only stressed vowels have the full assortment, and unstressed vowels are virtually always centralized. If you choose to represent these vowels with full phonemes, then you have to provide centralized allophones for all of them, for which you will likely not find minimal pairs because English central vowels don't contrast. This is one of the problems with phonemic theories vs real phonetic data.

Comment: @JohnLawler I see, thanks. Would you still be ok with the claim that (in, for example, your normal pronunciation) the initial unstressed vowel in _experience_ is **phonetically** closer to the stressed vowel in _fish_ as opposed to the stressed vowel in _best_ (hence the choice to represent it phonemically as /ɪ/)?

Comment: I can't measure distances that small without instruments.

Comment: I am almost certain that I pronounce all three with same initial vowel sound.

Comment: Native American English speaker here. I've never said /ɪkˈspɪr.i.əns/. It's always been /ɛkˈspɪr.i.əns/. Also, I say /ˌɛk.spɚˈtiːs/. Not sure how common my pronunciation is, but I must have received it from my friends and family in the mid-Atlantic region of the east coast. If I heard someone say /ˌɛk.spɚˈtiːz/ I'd think it was strange.

Comment: Watching some YouTube videos, I see how a lot of Americans do in fact say /ɪkˈspɪr.i.əns/, I just never noticed before.

Comment: @ToddWilcox This is why we teach phonetics. Nobody else pays attention to the actual sounds, which are the real language. And vary **widely** from what one might expect, given only Anglophone "English" classes.

Answer (score 7):

This is a case of *vowel reduction* (see [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_and_vowel_reduction_in_English)). In "expert," the initial syllable has primary stress. In "expertise," it has secondary stress. But in "experience," it is entirely unstressed, so (as often happens) the vowel in the syllable is reduced to /ɪ/.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and link. Could you please help me identify other pairs of words where /ɪ/ functions as the unstressed counterpart of primarily stressed /ɛ/?

Comment: Dunno if "vowel reduction" happens with *all* words where initial would-be /ɛ/ is unstressed, but for me it certainly does with ***enclose, encase, enamel, enigma, enough,...***

Comment: @FumbleFingers I guess the same process accounts for the difference in terms of the 1st syllable's vowel in the words "present (noun)" /ˈpɹɛzənt/ versus "present (verb)" /pɹɪˈzɛnt/, is that right?

Comment: I would think so, yes. And you should also bear in mind that in *many* contexts for many speakers, that unstressed initial vowel gets even *further* reduced to just a schwa.